# Alternate results per categories in ElasticSearch results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 300k items to get results from an ES index.

Some categories have 100k+ items while others have 1k or less. I want to avoid items from smaller categories being at the end of the results; at the same time, I don't want to prioritise these categories all the time either.

For these reasons **I'd like to alternate results per category**. Let's say show 2 results per category (if any result left) at a time:

```
- cat 1 result
- cat 1 result
- cat 2 result
- cat 2 result
- cat 3 result # only one result in that category
- cat 1 result
- cat 1 result
- cat 2 result
- etc.
```

*This is a simplified, there are more categories and all categories wouldn't necessarily have results for the current query.*

This can obviously be achieved with one query per category but that wouldn't be efficient and that would make pagination hard to implement.

Is there a way to achieve this with Elastic Search in one query? If not, is that possible with another search engine?

---

Only solution I've found so far is to use multi-search https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/search-multi-search.html and to merge the results after. I'm hoping to find a way in one query.

Comment: How many categories are we talking about and how many results do you want to pull in per query?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve alternating results per category in Elasticsearch, making sure a fair representation of each category *without* performing multiple queries per category, you can leverage the [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) with a [`top_hits` sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.12/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html), to fetch the top N documents you want from each category.

However, there is a limitation to keep in mind: Elasticsearch does not support interleaving search results from different buckets directly within a single query. So you will need to fetch the top hits for each category, and then programmatically interleave them in your application code.

A simplified Elasticsearch query would look like:

```json
{
  "size": 0,  // No need for the overall query hits, we are using aggregations
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category.keyword",
        "size": 10  // Adjust based on the number of categories you expect
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_category_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 2  // Fetch top 2 documents per category
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After you have executed this query, you will have the top 2 (or N) results for each category. You can then write application logic to interleave these results. Here, in Python pseudocode:

```py
results = execute_es_query()  # That is your ES query execution function
interleaved_results = []

# Assuming 'results' is the parsed JSON response from ES
buckets = results['aggregations']['categories']['buckets']

# Find the maximum number of hits in any category to determine the iteration count
max_hits = max(len(bucket['top_category_hits']['hits']['hits']) for bucket in buckets)

for i in range(max_hits):
    for bucket in buckets:
        try:
            # Attempt to add a result from each category
            interleaved_results.append(bucket['top_category_hits']['hits']['hits'][i])
        except IndexError:
            # That category had fewer than i results, so skip it
            continue

# Now 'interleaved_results' holds your documents in an alternating pattern
```

So that means doing a post-processing outside Elasticsearch, but it allows you to achieve the desired result with a single Elasticsearch query, plus some additional logic in your application to interleave the results.

Regarding pagination, you would need to adjust the `size` parameter in the `top_hits` aggregation based on your pagination logic and possibly maintain some state in your application to track pagination across different categories.